# How can I tweak Launcher and Menu Bar behavior?

Tags: unity

I mostly like Unity, although some things go too far in the MacOS direction for my liking and other things are simply not great usability practices that I would like to fix. Two things in particular kind of irk me a lot:

- I would like the menu bar for applications to be in the application itself and not in the top panel. I would also like it to be always displayed.
- I would like The position of locked Launcher icons to stay consistent. Sometimes when I run another application, it will rearrange icons which makes me have to think too hard about what keyboard shortcuts to use.

If you have a general resource to share for how to make changes to unity that would also suffice.

Comment: More info on the second problem ?, does it happen when a non-locked applications is running ?

Comment: If you do not already use it there are many aspects tweakable using the [Unity Tweak Tool](https://launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool).

Comment: I think we can safely ignore the second problem. I think things were open while I was installing things (which got a locked icon as they installed) and then as I closed windows things shifted around, giving me the impression that they'd keep doing that. Apologies for misinterpreting.

Answer (score 1):

#### For the menu bar :

type in terminal :

> sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu

for Firefox :
go to Tools –> Add-ons –> Extensions and disable ‘Global Menu Bar integration’.

#### For the launcher icons :

If a non locked application icon is running, it's icon should be at the bottom so it won't bother the arrangement of locked icons, just make sure all your frequent application's icons are locked.

#### For tweaking Ubuntu 13.04/13.10 :

Unity Tweak tool

> sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool

GNOME Tweak Tool :

> sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool